# In PHPExcel after uploading the data from Excel to database the control is not coming out of the loop

Tags: php

I am trying to upload the data from excel to MySQL database using PHPExcel. My code is working fine in localhost but when in server it is updating the data from excel to the database but the control is not coming out of the loop(Not terminating the process).
The same code is working fine for the excel file which as 3000 rows but not for 40000 rows.
Please help me

```
foreach($sheetData as $str)
    {

        if($z == $chunk_s)
        {
            break;
        }
        $z++;
        if($i == 1)
        {
            $i++;
            $val1 = $str['A'];
            $val2 = $str['B'];
            $val3 = $str['C'];
            $val4 = $str['D'];
            $val5 = $str['E'];
            $val6 = $str['F'];
            $val7 = $str['G'];
            $val8 = $str['H'];
            $val9 = $str['I'];
            $val10 = $str['J'];
            //$val11 = $str['K'];
            $val12 = $str['K'];
            $val13 = $str['L'];
            $val14 = $str['M'];
            $val15 = $str['N'];
            $val16 = $str['O'];
            $val17 = $str['P'];
            $val18 = $str['Q'];
            $val19 = $str['R'];
            $val20 = $str['S'];
            $val21 = $str['T'];

            if($val1 == "Order Date" && $val2 == "No" && $val3 == "Customer No." && $val4 == "Bill-to Name" && $val5 == "Bill-to Contact" && $val6 == "Phone No." && $val7 == "Bill-to City" && $val8 == "E-Mail" && $val9 == "Item No." && $val10 == "Description" && $val12 == "Maximum Agreed Repair Amount" && $val13 == "Status" && $val14 == "Your Reference" && $val15 == "Fault Code" && $val16 == "Resolution Code" && $val17 == "CHAWAGO Code" && $val18 == "Expected Finishing Date" && $val19 == "Amount Including VAT" && $val20 == "Posted Invoice No." && $val21 == "AirWay Bill No.")
            {
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Invalid Excel File.";
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {       
            $i++;   
            $val1 = $str['A'];
            $val2 = $str['B'];
            $val3 = $str['C'];
            $val4 = $str['D'];
            $val5 = $str['E'];
            $val6 = $str['F'];
            $val7 = $str['G'];
            $val8 = $str['H'];
            $val9 = $str['I'];
            $val10 = $str['J'];
            $val11 = "";
            $val12 = $str['K'];
            $val13 = $str['L'];
            $val14 = $str['M'];
            $val15 = $str['N'];
            $val16 = $str['O'];
            $val17 = $str['P'];
            $val18 = $str['Q'];
            $val19 = $str['R'];
            $val20 = $str['S'];
            $val21 = $str['T'];

            if($val1 == "END OF THE RECORD")
            {
                echo "End of the record is reached!<br /><br />";

                echo "<br />Number of New Records Added : " . $j . "<br />";
                echo "<br />Number of Updated Records  : " . $l . "<br />";
                echo "<br /><a href=''>Click here to go home.</a></pre>";
                exit;

                //break;
            }

            if($val1 == "" && $val2 == "" && $val3 == "" && $val4 == "" && $val5 == "" && $val6 == "" && $val7 == "" && $val8 == "" && $val9 == "" && $val10 == "" && $val12 == "" && $val13 == "" && $val14 == "" && $val15 == "" && $val16 == "" && $val17 == "" && $val18 == "" && $val19 == "" && $val20 == "" && $val21 == "")
            {
                echo "Blank row occurred. Please remove all the blank rows and start uploding the file.<br /><br />";
                echo "<br />Number of New Records Added : " . $j . "<br />";
                echo "<br />Number of Updated Records  : " . $l . "<br />";
                echo "<br /><a href=''>Click here to go home.</a></pre>";
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                $res1 = mysql_query("select * from servicedetails where Number = '$val2' and Customer_No = '$val3'");
                $num = mysql_num_rows($res1);
                if($num == 0)
                {                
                    $res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO servicedetails (Order_Date, Number, Customer_No, Bill_to_Name, Bill_to_Contact, Phone_No, Bill_to_City, EMail, Item_No, Description, Repair_Status_Code, Maximum_Agreed_Repair_Amount, Status, Your_Reference, Fault_Code, Resolution_Code, CHAWAGO_Code, Expected_Finishing_Date, Amount_Including_VAT, Posted_Invoice_No, AirWay_Bill_No) VALUES ('$val1', '$val2', '$val3', '$val4', '$val5', '$val6', '$val7', '$val8', '$val9', '$val10', '$val11', '$val12', '$val13', '$val14', '$val15', '$val16', '$val17', '$val18', '$val19', '$val20', '$val21')");         
                    $j++;
                    if($j > $chunk_s)
                    {
                        echo "<br />Number of New Records Added : " . $j . "<br />";
                        echo "<br />Number of Updated Records  : " . $l . "<br />";
                        echo "<br /><a href=''>Click here to go home.</a></pre>";
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $res = mysql_query("update servicedetails set Status = '$val13' where Number = '$val2' and Customer_No = '$val3'");
                    $l++;
                    if($l > $chunk_s)
                    {
                        echo "<br />Number of New Records Added : " . $j . "<br />";
                        echo "<br />Number of Updated Records  : " . $l . "<br />";
                        echo "<br /><a href=''>Click here to go home.</a></pre>";
                        exit;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Memory is the most obvious - what memory saving techniques are you using in your script (if any)? because it looks as though you're building a complete array of worksheet data in memory before doing your SQL updates

Comment: But it is executing all the rows in the Excel file

Comment: I have set the memory_limit and execution_time but still it is not working

Comment: What is inside `$chunk_s`?

Comment: You've changed the memory limit to what? And are you using any of the documented memory saving features of PHPExcel such as cell caching?

Comment: And what do you actually mean by "executing all the rows in the Excel file"? A row in an Excel file is just data, it doesn't execute

Comment: I have changed the memory limit to -1.

Comment: I mean it is inserting all the rows in the excel file to database. And i'm not using any documented memory saving feature.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say.

- Perhapes too many data?
- Script exceeding php memory?
- MySQL terminating because of too many calls?
- Does any of your Rows have the value `$val1 == "END OF THE RECORD`?
- What does `$sheetdata.size();` say?

You said

> the control is not coming out of the loop(Not terminating the process)

What do you mean by *control*?

Comment: But it is executing all the rows in the Excel file

Comment: I mean it is inserting all the rows which are in the excel file to the database. My problem is, after inserting the records which are in excel file to the database it is not terminating the process.

Comment: where would you expect it to end? You seem to have multiple opportunities. Normally the process should end by itself after hitting the last foreach..

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But this is not happening my case.

Comment: Have you tried shortening your excelfile to a few hundret or even just a few dozen lines? What happens then? What happens, when you only have 1 line? At what amount of lines does it "break"?

Comment: My code is working fine till 6K rows. If it exceeds this it is not woking properly.

Comment: try adding some debugging code that runs `if($i>6000)` (or whatever the exact amount is) and that immediatly prints crucial data like the value of the variables that could quit the code. Try to move towards your error step by step. If not otherwise possible, add a `print('now on codeline XYZ');` after every php-statement, then you will see in detail what the code does exactly.